# stuck trying to get instagram display picture link

Tags: php

I am stuck trying to achieve this,
So I'm trying to create a code that gets any instagram account display picture link, I need the link of the picture only, without downloading the picture

```
$url = "https://instagram.com/+ $instagram";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
// M-jxE is the div id of any profile photo on Instagram website
$first_step = explode( '<div id="M-jxE">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Comment: Are you sure $url is correct? It's not look like instagram account. Try with `"https://instagram.com/$instagram"`.
But I think it's not possible to get picture like that. `<div id="M-jxE">'` will change as you cannot expect. You have to use instagram API instead : https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: The $instagram is the instagram username which is stored in my database and it works fine when I echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?
$url = "https://instagram.com/ares566";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/og:image.*" content="(.*)"/ui',$content,$a);
echo $a[1];
```

The resulting array contains account profile pic in `$a[1]`
For example
`https://instagram.fhel2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9b1027bdefc161a364b1bd9644dd385e/5E0F07C1/t51.2885-19/11925728_748463271946117_836552725_a.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel2-1.fna.fbcdn.net`

Comment: I am glad! Mark my answer pls;)